# Evitar repetir funciones en un condicional

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero minimizar el siguiente pequeño bloque de codigo:

```
if jwinkler.get_jaro_distance(text,l1) >= 0.90 or jwinkler.get_jaro_distance(text, l2) >= 0.90 or jwinkler.get_jaro_distance(text,l3) >= 0.90:
    print('passed')
```

En realidad como verán, la función siempre es la misma, solo que cambia el segundo parámetro (l1, l2, l3). Se me ocurrió hacerlo así:

```
if True in [jwinkler.get_jaro_distance(text,x) >= 0.90 for x in [l1,l2,l3]]:
    print('passed')
```

Lo cual **funciona**, pero no me parece muy *Pythónico*. Existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Al contrario, lo veo mucho más "Pythónico" que tu primer construcción. A lo sumo yo preferiría hacer `if any([jwinkler.get_jaro_distance(text,x) >= 0.90 for x in [l1,l2,l3]]):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma *pythónica* sería la siguiente:

```
if any(jwinkler.get_jaro_distance(text,x) >= 0.90 for x in [l1,l2,l3]):
    print('passed')
```

**Explicación**

- `any()` espera un iterable como parámetro. En este caso se le pasa una *expresión generadora* (observa que no la he puesto entre corchetes, pues de haberlo hecho sería una *comprensión de listas*)
- `any()` va extrayendo elementos del iterable y tan pronto como encuentra un `True`, retorna `True`.

**Ventajas sobre tu solución**

- Se evita crear la lista intermedia, por tanto es más eficiente en memoria. Una expresión generadora es *lazy*, no crea un nuevo elemento hasta que se lo pedimos iterando sobre ella. En cambio una comprensión de listas crea todos los elementos y devuelve la lista que los contiene.
- Se evita evaluar elementos posteriores si se encuentra un `True` pronto. En este sentido se comporta como el `or` en una expresión booleana. Esto se conoce como *cortocircuito lógico*. Por tanto puede ser más eficiente también en tiempo de ejecución (a menos que todos los elementos sean `False` en cuyo caso hay que evaluarlos todos de todas formas).

PD: También tienes `all()` que es similar a `any()`, pero sólo retorna `True` si todos los elementos son `True`. En este caso el cortocircuito lógico se produce tan pronto como se encuentra un `False` pues en ese caso ya puede retornar `False` sin evaluar el resto.

Answer (score 0):

Hace unas semanas me pasó algo parecido a lo que nadie supo darme respuesta más que la que tu mismo das, así que supongo que habrá que conformarse, desde luego mucho mejor que la primera opción.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, sino un comentario. Por favor bórrala y conviértela en un comentario a la pregunta.